# Python crontab adding newline character automatically and disabling other cron job

Tags: python, cron

I've written a python script to run certain cron jobs and using crontab for the same.

Following is the code snippet:

```
import os
import inspect
from crontab import CronTab

def add_cron_job(scripts_list,frequency):
    my_cron = CronTab(user='simrat')
    for script in scripts_list:
        if not cron_exists(my_cron,script):
            command = 'python {}'.format(script)
            job = my_cron.new(command=command, comment=script)
            job.minute.every(frequency)

    my_cron.write()

def cron_exists(my_cron, script):
    for job in my_cron:
        if job.comment == script:
            return True
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Frequency of every 1 minute
    test_script = ['test1.py', 'test2.py']
    add_cron_job(test_script,1)

    #Frequency of every 1 day
    test_script2 = ['test3.py']
    add_cron_job(test_script2,1440)
```

Following is the output of 'crontab -e' (notice additional spaces added)

```
* * * * * python test1.py # test1.py
* * * * * python test2.py # test2.py

*/1440 * * * * python test3.py # test3.py
```

When I re-run the python cron_job script, it somehow disables the last cron_job(test3.py) and following is the output of crontab file:

```
* * * * * python test1.py # test1.py
* * * * * python test2.py # test2.py

# DISABLED LINE
# */1440 * * * * python test3.py # test3.py

*/1440 * * * * python test3.py # test3.py
```

along with an error it throws on console:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "crontab"
```

So my question is 3 fold:

1. Why is additional space at the top of the command when running my_cron.write()?
2. Why does it disable the last cron job instead of ignoring it as it already exists (def cron_exits should have taken care of that)
3. What's the signifance of the error thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran you code and got following error in second run:

```
'1440', not in 0-59 for Minutes
```

I changed 1440 to 14 and ran code multiple times. And found same code every time (without deleting)

```
* * * * * python test1.py # test1.py
* * * * * python test2.py # test2.py

*/14 * * * * python test3.py # test3.py
```

I have not read complete `CronTab` code but it is clear that they have put some validator during reading existing cron commands but they are not validating it during writing.

Also i called `add_cron_job` with different arguments and found each time `my_cron.write()` is called it is adding a new line. ***This is not a bug but a feature.***

***Finally***
`No handlers could be found for logger "crontab"` is logging issue. Try this [Crontab Logger issue](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab/issues/22)

Comment: Adding empty lines is harmless, but calling it a "feature" is a stretch. It should not be hard to check if the last entry ends with a newline and only adding one if it is missing.

Comment: @tripleee new line is added by `CronTab` code and can't be changed from given code in question (object reference). If you don't want extra new line then you must open a feature request on their public repo. I don't think SO can help with this. Their code is showing `Copyright 2017`, I guess that they must have put new line willingly. Otherwise it would have not exist for so long.